# $E\subseteq [0,1], m(E\cap(E+t))=(m(E))^2$ for all $|t|\leq 1/2$. what is $m(E)$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

$E\subseteq [0,1], m(E\cap(E+t))=(m(E))^2$ for all $|t|\leq 1/2$. what is $m(E)$?

if $t=0$, then $m(E\cap(E+0))=m(E)=(m(E))^2$ so $m(E)=0,1$.

if $m(E)=1$, then $m(E\cap(E+1/2))=1/2\not=1^2=(m(E))^2$, so I conclude that $m(E)=0$.

is this correct? actually I was suggested to show first that $\lim_{t\rightarrow0}m(E\cap(E+t))=m(E)$ and I did, but I didn't use this fact in my answer. so I'm little worried if I did something wrong...

Comment: Seems good to me. The thing with the limit would be helpful if you only knew that the assumption holds for $0 <|t|\leq 1/2$.

Comment: Why $m(E\cap(E+1/2))=1/2$ ?

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM because if $m(E)=1$, then $E=[0,1]-Z$ where $m(Z)=0$, so $E\cap (E+1/2)=([0,1]-Z)\cap([1/2,3/2]-(Z+1/2))=[0,1/2]-(Z\cap (Z+1/2))$, and $m(Z+1/2)=m(Z)=0$, $m(Z\cap (Z+1/2))=0$.

Comment: Regarding $m(E)=1\implies m(E\cap (E+1/2))=1/2:$  You don't need equality:  $E\cap (E+1/2)\subset [1/2,1]$ so  $1/2\geq m(E\cap (E+1/2))=m(E)^2,$ which implies $1/\sqrt 2\;\geq m(E).$